Import Errors for Custom Django Apps in XBlock Development on OpenEdX Palm Version
I’m having trouble importing custom Django apps in an Open edX XBlock. Even though the Django application is installed in the Open edX environment, I'm encountering errors.
The video_rating custom Django application is installed and working perfectly in this environment.
onlineoffline is my XBlock.

2024-07-22 10:43:36,866 WARNING 32 [xblock.plugin] [user None] [ip None] plugin.py:144 - Unable to load XBlock ‘onlineoffline’
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xblock/plugin.py”, line 141, in load_classes
yield (class_.name, cls.load_class_entry_point(class))
File “/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xblock/plugin.py”, line 70, in load_class_entry_point
class = entry_point.load()
File “/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py”, line 2517, in load
return self.resolve()
File “/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py”, line 2523, in resolve
module = import(self.module_name, fromlist=[‘name’], level=0)
File “/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onlineoffline/init.py”, line 1, in
from .onlineoffline import OnlineOfflineClassXBlock
File “/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onlineoffline/onlineoffline.py”, line 4, in
from openedx.features.video_rating.models import UserFeedbackSave,Questions,Type,Ratings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘openedx.features.video_rating’


To resolve the issue with installing an XBlock in Open edX, follow these steps:

Copy the LMS requirements folder from the container to your host server:
tutor local copyfrom lms /openedx/requirements /home/ubuntu/Palm/volumes/requirements


Create a docker-compose.override.yml file to override the default volumes:
touch $TUTOR_ROOT/env/local/docker-compose.override.yml


Add the following content to the docker-compose.override.yml file to mount the requirements folder:
version: "3.7"
services:
  lms:
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/Palm/volumes/requirements:/openedx/requirements
  cms:
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/Palm/volumes/requirements:/openedx/requirements


Restart the Tutor environment with:
tutor local stop
tutor local start -d


Create a private.txt file in the mounted requirements folder:
/home/ubuntu/Palm/volumes/requirements/private.txt


Add the XBlock installation details to the private.txt file:
git+https://<git_access_token>@github.com/admin/xblock.git@<branch_name>


Rebuild and launch the Tutor environment:
tutor local build
tutor local launch


If the XBlock still isn't installed, you can manually install it inside the LMS container:
tutor local exec lms bash
pip install -r /openedx/requirements/private.txt



These steps should help you successfully install the XBlock and resolve any related errors.

Thank you, Himanshu, for putting so much effort into this task. Thanks a lot!
